# How to handle jsonarray string uploaded to php server?

Tags: php, android

cI'm using this code to upload a jsonarray to a server (maybe there is a better way of doing this):

```
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_a", json_a.toString()));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

The response I am getting in LogCat is:

```
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): The response text is POST = array (
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'json_a' => '[name=Mike, datetime=2012-04-10 21:29]\\",\\"[name=Roger, datetime=2012-03-10 21:29]\\"]\\"]',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): )
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): GET = array (
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): )
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): request = array (
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Content-Length' => '174',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Host' => 'graasdfon.hostei.com',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Connection' => 'Keep-Alive',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'User-Agent' => 'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601):   'Expect' => '100-Continue',
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): )
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): 
04-10 23:05:39.833: D/ProviderTester(601): <!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code -->
```

The php script server side looks like this:

```
<?php

$out="POST = " . var_export($_POST, true) . "\n";
$out.="GET = " . var_export($_GET, true) . "\n";
$out.="request = " . var_export(getallheaders(), true) . "\n";
print $out;

?>
```

I see that 'json_a' => '[name=Mike, datetime=2012-04-10 21:29]\",\"[name=Roger, datetime=2012-03-10 21:29]\"]\"]' contains the data I want, but How do I take the names and dates out of the object?

EDIT:
The when I print out the JSON object in logcat, this is what it looks like (not response from server):

```
 4-10 23:33:36.013: I/JSONInfo(601): JSON object: ["[name=mike, datetime=2012-04-10 23:33]","[name=red, datetime=2012-04-10 23:12]"]
```

Im not sure if ["[name=mike, datetime=2012-04-10 23:33]","[name=red, datetime=2012-04-10 23:12]"] is a correct json object it's just the array printed into a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON was correct you could use `json_decode()` to get your data as an array or object. As it is, it doesn't look like what you're sending is valid JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's in proper json format. I make the JSONArray object in android/java then turn it inot a string and send it to a server with a php script and echo back what I have sent. If it's not proper I'm not sure what I should change.

Comment: hmm, mybe ill build the string myself in android, upload it, then worry about makingit into a json object

Comment: [{"name":"Mike", "datetime":"2012-04-10 21:29"},{"name":"Roger", "datetime":"2012-03-10 21:29"}]

Comment: @Stagleton Based on your edit, it looks like the JSON is being corrupted somewhere between your `toString()` call and the response you receive. I'd expect something like what @Mikey has given above - with matching braces/brackets. What do you get if you use `json_decode()` in your PHP script? If it doesn't return anything then the JSON is not well-formed on arrival to your PHP script.

Comment: hmm it might be easier just to make a properly formated string and uplaod it

Comment: I got it into the format that looks like correct json, but when I try to put it into a jsonarray and echo a part of the array back I get an error. How can I see if json_decode is working correctly? If I run the function before and send back the input string I used to make the array, no error is thrown and I see the string. Does that mean json_decode() works?